# 22 push ups for PTSD in the military and police

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Here is the conudrum. I am doing 22 push-ups every day for 22 days. Each of those days I have to nominate one person person to do the challenge, so at the end of my 22 days i will have  nominated 22 people. Each of those people, in turn, have to nominate one person every day for their 22 days. I am trying to determine how many people in total will have been nominated by myself and the people I nominate the people they nominate subsequently, and so on, within my 22 days. The timeline is only my 22 days.

Comment: Look at  how many do push-ups on day one, two, three and four, and see if you can spot the pattern.

Comment: You won't last 22 days; at some point, one of those nominated, by you or by your nominee or by your nominee's nominee, will want to know who started the madness, and they'll know who you are and where you live.

Comment: What do PTSD, the military, or the police have to do with the question?

Comment: And what do calculus or linear algebra have to do with this question?

Comment: May be doing a lot of push ups together and then going for a drink is a good way to fight PTSD? I'm no psychologist, but studies of our WWII veterans showed that the more socially active ones were less likely to develop these problems.

Comment: $$\text{What?}$$ Send this to the puzzling Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't nominate someone on day one.  Someone nominates you on day 1, and you do your push-ups with your sponsor.  Day 2 you find your first nominee, and do push-ups with your nominee.

Otherwise you would never get started.  Al nominates Bill who nominate Craig who nominates Dave and everyone in the world is nominated on day one.

Next, if everyone follows the rules of the game, the pyramid grows forever.
Since the population is finite, you will surprisingly quickly run out of people to nominate.

Day 1, you do push-ups with your sponsor.  We are not going to count your sponsor. -- 1 participant

Day 2, you nominate 1 person -- 2 participants

Day 3, you nominate 1 more person, person and your first nominee nominates 1 person -- 4 participants

If every participant nominates one person, the number of people playing the game doubles every day.

Day $n, n<22$ -- $2^{n-1}$

At least until the day that you have completed the challenge, and are no longer nominating people

Day 22 -- $2^{21}$ ~ 2 million participants

Day 23 -- you don't participate, nor did you nominate. --  $(2^{21} - 1)\cdot2 = 2^22 - 2$

Day 24 -- $(2^22 - 2)\cdot 2 - 2^2 = 2^{23} - 2 (2^2)$
Day 25 -- $(2^23 - 2\cdot 2^2)\cdot 2 - 2^3 = 2^{23} - 3 (2^3)$

Day n (with $n>22$) -- $2^{n-1} - (n-22)2^{n-1-22}$

By day 29 -- everyone in America has received (or recently has completed) the challenge.

By day 33 -- more than half the world is participating.

By day 34 -- sorry out of people.